# How to mark messages from 'me' as read when I move them to the Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am configuring Outlook to work more like Gmail

1. Display messages in [conversations](http://www.davidgrant.ca/make_outlook_behave_gmail)
2. Move [messages](http://www.davidgrant.ca/make_outlook_behave_gmail) I send to the Inbox, so they appear in the conversation
3. Implemented an [Archive](http://lifehacker.com/5175347/add-a-gmail+like-archive-button-to-microsoft-outlook) macro/folder

However, I cannot get messages that I send, which are moved to the Inbox, to be marked as read. I guess it's because I'm not actually *sending* my messages to the Inbox, I'm just copying them. And it appears that rules work only on *sent* and *received* messages.

Here are my rules (text only)

#### CC Sent Messages to Inbox

- Apply this rule after I send the message
- move a copy to the Inbox Folder

#### Mark Messages from Self as Read

- Apply this rule after the message arrives
- from Anthony Mastrean
- mark it as read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conversation view, only the first message isn't kept in the inbox conversation. That one can be found in the Sent Items. Give up.

Answer (score 0):

First I enabled "Show as Conversation".

Next, I created a rule that started with "Move messages from someone to a folder".

The rule included "apply the rule after the message arrives from" me, followed by move it to the Inbox folder, followed by "mark it as read", followed by "stop processing more rules".